# Is it possible to programmatically push files to a wireless SD card?

Tags: applescript, wifi

Is it possible to programmatically push files to a wireless SD card - like a [www.eye.fi](http://www.eye.fi) card?

I use a Mac and thought I could do this using some AppleScript - but have not found a way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eye-fi card relies on image files being written to a specific directory in the card before they'll transfer them.  Beyond that it works exactly like a memory card.

Write a file to it as if you're writing a regular memory card, and as long as it's a jpg image file of reasonable size, and in an appropriate directory (something under \DCIM\ probably) and they should transfer.

If you're having trouble, double check that it works with your camera, and find out where your camera puts the images on the card, and duplicate that.  You might even try naming them similar names to the types of images your camera produces.

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can treat it just like an external hard drive (plug the memory card in and figure out where the mount point is).

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants to send files to it while its in another device, not plug it in and use it to transmit files like an antena directly connected to the machine.

Comment: I agree with you here. Still have to buy the actual card and try it out... ;D